# Can I use my iPhone 4s (jailbroken to unlock) in Australia?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

I have an Irish iPhone 4s already jailbroken for Italian Vodafone. I must use the iPhone 5 SIM with an adapter and the phone works only with my Italian SIM.

Now I am in Australia and I would like to unlock and use it with my Australian SIM! Is it possible? Do I need a new jailbreak?

Answer (score 1):

if your iPhone is already unlocked (e.g. jailbroken and ultrasn0w installed from Cydia) then you don't need to do anything. Just put in the SIM you want and it *should* work.